# undefined control sequence for integral

Tags: errors

l.28    \oiint
             \phi \cdot \hat{nmath} dS,
?

This is my error. I cannot figure out what is wrong. This equation is nested in a \begin{equation} \end{equation}, so that is why i do not have the $$. Thanks.

Comment: Are you definitely loading a package that provides `\oiint`. I think you need `esint` for that. Also what are you hoping for with `\hat{nmath}`? A final PS, you generally want a small space before your differential, thus: `\, dS`

Comment: I did not know /oiint needed a specific package. I will add that. I want to write the dot product with the unit normal vector, hence the \hat{nmath} but I am not sure if there is a better way to do that. So i include a \ before my differential?

Comment: Are you looking for `\hat{\mathbf{n}}`, that seems more standard: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/NormalVector.html. It's good to include a `\,` or sometimes people use `\;` You want a small space

Comment: I keep getting: "! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=5000].
\end #1->\csname end#1
                      \endcsname \@checkend {#1}\expandafter \endgroup \if@e...
<*> \end
        
!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!"

Comment: you really need to ask a new question and provide a full Minimum Working Example. It seems likely to me, given the error message you have reproduced there, that you are having problems downstream and the `\oiint` problem has been solved. N.B. my other little tidbits about normal vectors and typesetting differentials were just that: tidbits. They shouldn't affect anything else, although I can't imagine any way that `\hat{nmath}` could give you a nice result! :P